# First render in Play 2.3.x does not use correct language

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using simple middleware to update the `Result`

```
  object WithLanguage extends ActionFunction[User, User] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: User[A], block: (User[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      if(request.cookies.get(Play.langCookieName).isEmpty){
        val lang: Lang = Lang.get(request.user.language).getOrElse(play.api.i18n.Lang.preferred(request.acceptLanguages))
        block(request).withLang(lang))

      } else {
        block(request)
      }
    }
  }
```

But the first response is not rendered with the appropriate language - on refresh yes.

I can get it to work by performing a circular redirect in the case of setting a new cookie `Future(Redirect(request.uri).withLang(...)` but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Have you tried modifying request before calling block?
block(request.withLang(lang))

Comment: Thanks @mavarazy yeah the request doesn't have the method `withLang` only the Result does

Comment: Can you modify request and set a cookie, before processing it in block?

Comment: Yeah definitely, i have all of that code available in the withLang function and I could copy it -- which i did initially. but what I'm hoping to do is override the `implicit def request2lang` somehow on that first request - or at least explicitly provide the `implicit val lang: Lang` so template pulls form that. Modifying the request makes me feel like i'm breaking isolation (http is sort of abstracted away in these action layers)

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works ... It's possible to modify the request headers imperatively, but writing this way feels wrong.

```
object WithLanguage extends ActionFunction[User, User] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: User[A], block: (User[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      if(request.cookies.get(Play.langCookieName).isEmpty){
        val cookies = Cookies(request.headers.get(COOKIE)).cookies + (Play.langCookieName -> Cookie(Play.langCookieName, request.user.language.code))
        val updatedHeaders = new Headers {
          val data: Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = (request.headers.toMap + (COOKIE -> Seq(Cookies.encode(cookies.values.toSeq)))).toSeq
        }
        val modifiedRequest = User(
          user = request.user, 
          request = Request(request.copy(headers = updatedHeaders), request.body)
        )
        block(modifiedRequest).map(_.withLang(request.user.language)) // redundant cookie set on result
      } else {
        block(request)
      }
    }
  }
```